# How to week start date and week end date in SQL Server by month number or month name in a current year , week start with monday and end with friday

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @WeekNo int= 4
DECLARE @Year int=2015

SELECT 
    DATEADD(wk, @WeekNo - 1, DATEADD(yy, @Year - 1900, 0)) AS WeekStart,
    DATEADD(wk, @WeekNo, DATEADD(yy, @Year - 1900, 0)) - 1 AS WeekEnd
```

Comment: sorry, what?...

Answer (score 1):

@Rafal is using @Month and the undocumented system table 'spt_values' (which Microsoft could decide to change at any time). For longevity purposes, I do not recommend referencing this table.

Although I said earlier that this problem cannot really be solved effectively, what I meant to say was "this problem cannot be solved effectively **without a set of assumptions**"

My assumptions are:

- *Your environment is set to Day Of Week Start = Monday*
- *That you don't care about half-weeks since either Monday or Friday will be missing*

The code:

```
DECLARE @WeekNo int= 1 DECLARE @Year int=2007
IF @WeekNo = 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT CASE
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)) = 2 THEN CAST(DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                    ELSE CAST('Irrelevant: The week selected is a half-week with either a missing Monday or Friday' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                END AS Week_Start
            ,CASE
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)) = 2 THEN CAST(DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,05) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                    ELSE CAST('Irrelevant: The week selected is a half-week with either a missing Monday or Friday' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                END AS Week_End
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT CASE
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0))) = 1 THEN DATEADD(dd,1,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0)))
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0))) = 3 THEN DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0)))
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0))) = 4 THEN DATEADD(dd,-2,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0)))
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0))) = 5 THEN DATEADD(dd,-3,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0)))
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0))) = 6 THEN DATEADD(dd,-4,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0)))
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0))) = 7 THEN DATEADD(dd,-5,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0)))
                END  AS Week_Start
            ,CASE
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0))) = 1 THEN DATEADD(dd,4,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0)))
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0))) = 3 THEN DATEADD(dd,3,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0)))
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0))) = 4 THEN DATEADD(dd,2,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0)))
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0))) = 5 THEN DATEADD(dd,1,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0)))
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0))) = 6 THEN DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0)))
                    WHEN DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0))) = 7 THEN DATEADD(dd,-2,DATEADD(ww,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,01,01)),0)))
                END  AS Week_End
    END
```

Comment: I've use this table only for testing purposes. For production is useless.

Comment: HAHA, that's awesome.  Your solution is extremely clever, I hope you don't mind I took it and tweaked it.  But now you have a solution for Production!!!

Comment: No problem. Together we prepared really good solution.

Answer (score 0):

This solution mimics @Rafal's but uses a recursive CTE to create a set of numbers instead of relying on master..spt_values.

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 2015,
        @Month INT = 10;

WITH iterator as
(
SELECT 1 as number
UNION ALL
SELECT 1+number
FROM iterator
WHERE number<=31
)


SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(week, datediff(week, 0, DATEADD(DAY,i.number,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,@Month,1))), 0) AS weekstart,
    DATEADD(week, datediff(week, 0, DATEADD(DAY,i.number,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,@Month,1))), 4) AS weekend
FROM iterator as i
WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(DAY,i.number,DATEFROMPARTS(@Year,@Month,1))) = @month
```

Comment: Hi thanks reply for me thanks  a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This query should meet your expectations:

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 2015,
        @Month INT = 10


SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(week, datediff(week, 0, DATEADD(DAY,sv.number,DATEADD(YEAR,@Year-1900,DATEADD(MONTH,@Month-1,0)))), 0) AS weekstart,
      DATEADD(week, datediff(week, 0, DATEADD(DAY,sv.number,DATEADD(YEAR,@Year-1900,DATEADD(MONTH,@Month-1,0)))), 4) AS weekend
FROM master..spt_values sv
WHERE
   sv.type = 'P'
   AND sv.number <= 31
   AND DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(DAY,sv.number,DATEADD(YEAR,@Year-1900,DATEADD(MONTH,@Month-1,0)))) = @month
```

Comment: Hi i am using Sql Server 2008 while executing above query i am getting following error. DATEFROMPARTS' is not a recognized built-in function name.
can you rewrite this in  Sql Server 2008.

Comment: I corrected query for SQL2008

Comment: Hi it's working fine thanks for your response.

Comment: I'm glad that is work for you. I hope that you accept my answer.

Comment: Hi Rafał Wojtaszek again need to modify this query. what need exact is

Comment: the first week of month includes previous month last week days that's should not be happened and as well as last week of month includes next month first week days that's should not be happened,week start and end days must be in cuurent month only can you verify that , hope you understood thanks.